# nedmalloc: where does mem>=fm come from?

Tags: c, debugging, memory-management, winapi, nedmalloc

While implementing nedmalloc into my application, I am frequently hitting a situation when nedmalloc refuses to free a block of memory, claiming it did not allocate it.

I am using v1.06beta1_svn1151 version.

While debugging I have come up to the point I see a particular condition which is failing, all other (including magic numbers) succeed. The condition is this:

```
if((size_t)mem-(size_t)fm>=(size_t)1<<(SIZE_T_BITSIZE-1)) return 0;
```

On Win32 this seems to be equivalent to:

```
if((int)((size_t)mem-(size_t)fm)<0) return 0;
```

Which seems to be the same as:

```
if((size_t)mem<(size_t)fm) return 0;
```

In my case I really see mem < fm. What I do not understand now is, where does this condition come from. I cannot find anything which would guarantee the fm <= m anywhere in code. Yet, "select isn't broken": I doubt it would really be a bug in nedmalloc, most likely I am doing something wrong somewhere, but I cannot find it. Once I turn debugging features of nedmalloc on, the problem goes away.

If someone here understands inner working of nedmalloc, could you please explain to me why is fm <= mem guaranteed?

Comment: I can't find this in the current nedmalloc source code. Which version are you using?

Comment: Crazy. I did not expect upvote for this kind of detailed technical minutes question, esp. not this soon. Either there is somebody out there who likes and understands this stuff, or the monkey programmers are already here on the SO, up-voting random questions? (But how on earth did they get enough reputation to vote?) No matter what, I hope someone will answer - in this case this is more important to me than reputation.

Comment: you posed a well described question, which will hopefully give rise to some explanation about an interesting issue like memory management, so no wonder that someone upvoted you.

Comment: I upvoted because (a) the question is clear and also interesting and puzzling, (b) you did some thinking of yourself, and (c) your "select isn't broken" attitude.

Comment: As it turned out it is question about a bug in a specific version, I suggest closing as "too localized".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see now for this line there was added a comment /* See if mem is lower in memory than mem */ and it was disabled using #if 0 in beta svn1159. The condition is not mature and it is probably wrong (it is still left in the Linux specific part of the code - most likely wrong there as well?)

Lesson learned: "*beta* select can be broken".

Comment: Haha, yeah, after you updated your post to include that you are using an svn version, and I noticed that the line you mention is not in the current stable version, I was beginning to doubt select as well... :)

Comment: What to do with this now? The whole question point seems to be moot now - it does not seem to me StackOverflow should document already fixed bugs in various libs. I guess I will probably vote to delete this question? (Still, I am very glad to have asked it - your question about which version helped me a lot).

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that `SIZE_T_BITSIZE` is the number of bits in `size_t` type, so shifting 1 by `SIZE_T_BITSIZE - 1` will give you `(SIZE_MAX + 1) / 2` (mathematical) value.  So the condition is testing if `(size_t)mem - (size_t)fm` is greater than or equal to the mathematical value of `(SIZE_MAX + 1) / 2`.

This is not the same as `(int)((size_t)mem - (size_t)fm) < 0`.  Further, if `mem` and/or `fm` are cast to `size_t`, which is an unsigned type, the arithmetic happens in unsigned types, which means that the difference cannot be less than 0.  So, even if `(size_t)mem` is less than `(size_t)fm`, `(size_t)mem - (size_t)fm` is never going to be less than 0.  It is equal to the difference `mem - fm` plus `SIZE_MAX` plus `1`, which is a positive value.  Converting that value to an `int` may overflow, which is implementation-defined, or may not overflow, in which case you end up with a positive value.

So, to answer your question, if `(size_t)mem` is less than `(size_t)fm`, you probably have a bug *before* that point.

What is `m`?  By `m`, do you mean `mem`?

*Edit*: Looks like a bug in `nedmalloc`, for reasons I mentioned above.  The code in question has been [commented out in the latest version](http://tnfox.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/tnfox/trunk/src/nedmalloc/nedmalloc.c?r1=1152&r2=1158).

Comment: I am assuming Win32 (as indicated by a tag).

Comment: Yes, m should be mem. Thanks for pointing out, this is corrected now.